# fast moving cursor?

Tags: scrolling, cursor

What can I add to my .emacs to make the cursor move more quickly? Specifically, I'm looking for faster rates for (holding arrow-keys and C-arrow keys (ie skipping over whitespace with my current config)).

I realize I can tune this at the OS level, but was hoping for something emacs specific.

Comment: WD40? ---------

Comment: Scroll with `PageDown` and `PageUp`?

Comment: Emacs has many commands for moving forward by bigger units that characters, e.g. words, sentences, paragraphs, etc.  Perhaps you should be using those instead.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12219388/215924

Comment: @AndrewSwann already have that covered. I'm just looking for a faster cursor rate of movement..

Comment: You can't do this through emacs, it has to come from the OS.

Comment: Although I've not seen an Emacs command for this, I suppose one could create a special minor mode that skips over consecutive whitespace characters when navigating giving the impression that the cursor is moving quicker. But it is not the same as reducing key repeat rate in the operating system itself. Moreover this special mode will still not be as fast as semantic navigation tools, of which there are plenty in Emacs.

Comment: I didn't test it myself but “You can counter this sluggishness by setting the variable `fast-but-imprecise-scrolling` to a non-`nil` value. This instructs the scrolling commands not to fontify any unfontified text they scroll over, instead to assume it has the default face. This can cause Emacs to scroll to somewhat wrong buffer positions when the faces in use are not all the same size, even with single (i.e., without auto-repeat) scrolling operations.” From https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Scrolling.html